# How to create automatic Cloudwatch alarm on New EC2 instance creation

Tags: amazon-web-services, automation, aws-lambda, amazon-cloudwatch

I want to create a lambda function that gets triggered whenever a new EC2 instance is created, this Lambda function should configure StatusCheck alarm on this new instance automatically. So that I don't have to manually configure cloudwatch alarm each time a new instance is created. Can someone help with code for lambda function that accomplishes this?

I have something like this:

```
   response = client.put_metric_alarm(
    AlarmName='StatusCheckFailed-Alarm-for-i-1234567890abcdef0',
    AlarmActions=[
        'arn:aws:sns:us-west-2:111122223333:my-sns-topic',
    ],
    MetricName='StatusCheckFailed',
    Namespace='AWS/EC2',
    Statistic='Maximum',
    Dimensions=[
        {
            'Name': 'InstanceId',
            'Value': 'i-1234567890abcdef0'
        },
    ],
    Period=300,
    Unit='Count',
    EvaluationPeriods=2,
    Threshold=1,
    ComparisonOperator='GreaterThanOrEqualToThreshold')
```

But I have to map instance ID from cloudwatch rule as an input to Lambda.  Because the function would trigger automatically so there is no way to put instance ID manually each time.

Comment: Any instance launch, or for example only instances launched by specific auto scaling group?

Comment: Any instance launch.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You will need two cloud watch rule to handle this as

- One for instance launch from auto-scaling group
- One for instance launch with EC2

Also, I am going to add **Launch** and **Terminatioin**

- On Launch (add alarm)
- On termination (delete alarm) to avoid reaching max limit

Autoscaling group CW rule:

```
{
  "source": [
    "aws.autoscaling"
  ],
  "detail-type": [
    "EC2 Instance Launch Successful",
    "EC2 Instance Terminate Successful"
  ]
}
```

Autoscaling Event:

```
{
  "version": "0",
  "id": "3e3c153a-8339-4e30-8c35-687ebef853fe",
  "detail-type": "EC2 Instance Launch Successful",
  "source": "aws.autoscaling",
  "account": "123456789012",
  "time": "2015-11-11T21:31:47Z",
  "region": "us-east-1",
  "resources": [
    "arn:aws:autoscaling:us-east-1:123456789012:autoScalingGroup:eb56d16b-bbf0-401d-b893-d5978ed4a025:autoScalingGroupName/sampleLuanchSucASG",
    "arn:aws:ec2:us-east-1:123456789012:instance/i-b188560f"
  ],
  "detail": {
    "StatusCode": "InProgress",
    "AutoScalingGroupName": "sampleLuanchSucASG",
    "ActivityId": "9cabb81f-42de-417d-8aa7-ce16bf026590",
    "Details": {
      "Availability Zone": "us-east-1b",
      "Subnet ID": "subnet-95bfcebe"
    },
    "RequestId": "9cabb81f-42de-417d-8aa7-ce16bf026590",
    "EndTime": "2015-11-11T21:31:47.208Z",
    "EC2InstanceId": "i-b188560f",
    "StartTime": "2015-11-11T21:31:13.671Z",
    "Cause": "At 2015-11-11T21:31:10Z a user request created an AutoScalingGroup changing the desired capacity from 0 to 1.  At 2015-11-11T21:31:11Z an instance was started in response to a difference between desired and actual capacity, increasing the capacity from 0 to 1."
  }
}
```

EC2 CW Rule:

```
{
  "source": [
    "aws.ec2"
  ],
  "detail-type": [
    "EC2 Instance State-change Notification"
  ],
  "detail": {
    "state": [
      "running",
      "terminated"
    ]
  }
}
```

EC2 Event:

```
{
  "version": "0",
  "id": "ee376907-2647-4179-9203-343cfb3017a4",
  "detail-type": "EC2 Instance State-change Notification",
  "source": "aws.ec2",
  "account": "123456789012",
  "time": "2015-11-11T21:30:34Z",
  "region": "us-east-1",
  "resources": [
    "arn:aws:ec2:us-east-1:123456789012:instance/i-abcd1111"
  ],
  "detail": {
    "instance-id": "i-abcd1111",
    "state": "running"
  }
}
```

So you can do rest of the logic base on the event, below example is base on javascript

If the event from the auto-scaling group

```
     if (event["source"] == "aws.autoscaling") {
          
          if (event["detail-type"] === "EC2 Instance Launch Successful"){
                let EC2_ID=event.detail.EC2InstanceId
               // Add alarm here
              // use EC2 instance ID
          }

     }
```

Same logic can be applied for EC2 events, where you can check the status

```
     if (event["source"] == "aws.ec2") {
          
          if (event.detail === "running"){
                let EC2_ID=event.detail.EC2InstanceId
               // Add alarm here
              // use EC2 instance ID
          }
         // same can be check for termination
          if (event.detail === "terminated"){
                let EC2_ID=event.detail.EC2InstanceId
               // remove alarm for this instance
              // use EC2 instance ID here to remove/delete alaram
          }

     }
```

Comment: Thank you very much, I have almost cracked it except one problem. I am using Python environment and when I try to get instance ID from event like this:

instance_id = event['detail']['instance-id']

It gives me error :  "errorMessage": "'$.detail'",
  "errorType": "KeyError",

How do i fix this?

Comment: seems like you are not loading json.`data = json.load(event)` then it should work `print(data["detail"]["EC2InstanceId"])`

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is [AWS CloudTrail](https://aws.amazon.com/cloudtrail/). It's a service that is used to monitor any and every API calls made to AWS for a given account.

> **Pro Tip:** AWS is API driven, everything you do, even on the console (UI) is translated into an API call to get the desired result.

The scenario described a very common one and AWS has addressed it in [Automating Amazon EC2 with CloudWatch Events - Amazon Elastic Compute Cloud](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/automating_with_cloudwatch_events.html). You can create a CloudTrail event trail for EC2 and configure it to trigger a lambda function. As you have described, this function can then do the necessary configurations.

I use this setup for a similar use case wherein monitoring for disk utilization and memory is configured for any new instance that any user or system spins up. This is just an additional check that makes sure if the correct/recommended AMI is not used, there is some process that goes in and makes sure the monitoring tools are in place.

*A note from my experience:
I prefer using S3 in between CloudTrail and Lambda i.e. CloudTrail would write the events to S3 and then the lambda function would be triggered via S3 events. This has the added benefit of persisting the events for later reference. If the data is not sensitive, you can choose to use S3 Lifecycle hooks to delete the data in some time or even use a cheaper storage option to keep the cost down.*

Comment: Thank you very much, but my problem remains, as it lies within the lambda function. How to create a status check alarm in Lambda basically using the instance ID of the instance which was just created is my question.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you were able to get an answer to your question about getting the instance id of the instance. here is how i did it:

```
def lambda_handler(event, context):
    cloudwatchclient = boto3.client('cloudwatch')
    eventdata = json.load(event)
    thisInstanceID = eventdata['detail']['instance-id']
```